# Javascript functions embedded in arguments run automatically?

Tags: javascript, xss

I am investigating defending against various types of attacks and I've found one I don't quite understand.

I have the following html:

```
<body onload="foo(''/alert(/Gotcha/)/'');">
<script>
   function foo(){
      alert("Inside Foo");
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this, you'll see an alert that says "/Gotcha/" followed immediately by one that says "Inside Foo".

What's going on?  Why is the alert in the argument (that foo doesn't even have) running?

What's more, if I remove any of those slashes or single-quotes in the argument, it doesn't work.

if I change it to

```
<body onload="foo('/alert(/Gotcha/)/');">
```

All I get is "Inside Foo".

if I change it to

```
<body onload="foo('/alert(Gotcha)/');">
```

or remove any of the /s I don't get anything.

What is it about the ' and the / that makes this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a complicated expression there so let's break it up:

`foo(''/alert(/Gotcha/)/'');`

1. JS interprets this as a call to a function `foo` with `''/alert(/Gotcha/)/''` as a parameter (functions in JS do not have hard params, you can send as many as you'd like, even if the function declaration does not specify them)
2. The parameter is evaluated as the string `''` followed by the division character `/`, followed by the `alert` function, then another division and another empty string
3. The parameter for the alert is evaluated since it's not a string, but a regular expression and the string representation is, incidentally, the same as the input regular expression string
4. The `alert` is executed with the string representation of the regex to evaluate the parameter for `foo` and the result of the whole parameter expression is `NaN` because the strings aren't divisible which doesn't really matter since the function `foo` does not use it
5. The function `foo` is executed.

Comment: Kudos for realizing that the slash is doing division, I totally missed that.

Comment: But actually, strings **are** divisible, because it converts them to numbers first. However, empty strings convert to the number `0`, and `0/0` is `NaN`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. As for division, yes, `0/0` gives `NaN`, but that's not the part that's giving `NaN` in this case. The result of the `alert` is `undefined` so that's the one that's giving `NaN` in the first place, i.e. `0/undefined/0`, but that's nitpicking. I didn't go into it in my answer since it doesn't directly relate to the question as that parameter is not used, but yeah, good point that I could've explained why it's `NaN`, too.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks.Follow up question though:  Why does 'onload=foo(alert(/Gotcha/));' work, but 'onload=foo(alert(Gotcha));' fail?  What is it about the /s inside the argument for alert that allows this to pass?

Comment: @djc6535 The slashes are part of the syntax for a regular expression literal, as in `str.test(/Got.*cha/)`. Without the slashes it's trying to access a variable named `Gotcha`.

Comment: @djc6535 It seems like this code was designed to be deliberately confusing, by using these operators in unusual ways. If you found it in malware, that's not surprising.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes it was malware, (Or rather, proof of susceptibility of malware) discovered on openbugbounty.org.  Thanks again with the clarification.  Replacing the / with ' works, and now I understand why.

Comment: 1.JS interprets this as a call to a function foo with ''/alert(/Gotcha/)/'' as a parameter (functions in JS do not have hard params, you can send as many as you'd like, even if the function declaration does not specify them). - This is not true at all. No string passed  as a function argument value gets evaluated/parsed, but assigned as is, to the arguments index or a named argument if present.

Comment: @BekimBacaj you are truly a lost cause... Please learn to read before making incorrect statements. The expression is parsed to get the parameter and in this case, that means evaluating the `alert` function to get it's return value in order to evaluate the whole expression in order to be able to use it as you so eagerly want to point out JS (and most every other language) works... You can't just skip steps...

Answer (score 0):

The reason the argument in the `foo` call runs is because it is being interpreted as JavaScript. The arguments you are passing in `foo(''/alert(/Gotcha/)/''` is essentially 2 strings and in the middle of them is a `alert` call.

Comment: How is it passing multiple arguments if there's no commas separating them?

Comment: @dandavis What second `alert`?

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments are all evaluated **before** the function is called. So when you write:

```
foo(alert('/Gotcha/'));
```

it first evaluates `alert('/Gotcha/')`, which causes `/Gotcha/` to be displayed. Then the return value of `alert()` is passed as a parameter to `foo()`. `foo()` ignores its parameter, but that doesn't matter for the first step.

When you change it to

```
foo('/alert(/Gotcha/)/');
```

then the argument is a literal string, not a function call. So evaluating it just returns the string contents, it doesn't call the `alert()` function.

I can't see any reason why

```
<body onload="foo('/alert(Gotcha)/');">
```

would behave any differently from

```
<body onload="foo('/alert(/Gotcha/)/');">
```

so I suspect that your actual code has a typo that you didn't copy here. Check your Javascript console for syntax error messages.

Comment: It is copy pasted directly.  Here's another example, simplified with the information provided by others above:  <body onload="foo(alert(/Gotcha/));"> works, but <body onload="foo(alert(Gotcha));"> does not even call foo.  No errors in the console

Comment: When I try it I see the following in the console: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Gotcha is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

---

**Q:** *"Javascript functions embedded in arguments run automatically?"*

---

**A:** It has nothing to do with function arguments. The ***foo*** function is there to simply add to the confusion of an already obfuscated expression. This is a simply a complicated way of writing an equivalent of:

```
onload="alert(/Gotcha/)"
```

which wants to alert the content of /Gotcha/ regex literal.

The regex literal provided in the string of the body onload assignment is simply the passive value of the alert function provided in that same string and has no share in what's going on there.

Everything else is simply a clever way of masking a simple assignment such as the above given `onload="alert(/Gotcha/)"` line of code.

**The only thing that makes it work is the fact that inline event assignments are strings that need to get evaluated in order to get executed.**

Therefore `eval( ''/alert(/Gotcha/)/'' )` will do the same. Or putting it all back in its original form: `eval( "foo(''/alert(/Gotcha/)/'');" )`.

So yes, it is possible to execute any kind of string content assigned inline to an element event. But then, so is the `setTimeout("foo(''/alert(/Gotcha/)/'');", 1000)` capable of doing exactly the same.

So, "no" it has nothing to do with function arguments, but with the parsing of string content to the inline event of document body element.

---

***EDIT:***

Inline JavaScript on strings containing html for Images is (for the reasons explained above on why that Gotcha alert works) the most dangerous code injection without the need of user input. That's because image elements can handle *onerror* events, to which any arbitrary block of code can be executed, as in:

```
<img 
    src="http://Idontexist.com/wrongfolder/missingimage.jpg" 
    onerror="your arbitrary, but well written (malicious) code here!"
>
```

Comment: Your answer answers a different question. `eval` or it's equivalent is not used here in any part since the arguments passed to `foo` are three values with a division sign between each of the values and the second value being a function **call**, not a function **reference** so it's evaluated for it's return value at once. Same thing with that inner function.

Comment: @Bikonja, you don't seem to understand the article as it's written, this reveals that you are unaware of the fact that inline events will automatically parse the string literal assigned to them just like eval function does; as does the first argument of setTimeout function and similar - and finally: That's the only reason why accepting inline event property assignments are considered dangerous... -So once again: The only reason that this expression works lies behind the fact that inline event property assignments behave just like js eval does.

Comment: C# doesn't have `eval` (not in the way JS does), yet you could do the same thing in C# (minus the unspecified parameter) because no, in this case, there is no `eval` going on, just plain old code execution. I do understand now, though, that you're talking about the placement of the code in question which, incidentally, is in an inline event handler declaration and yes, that does `eval`, but it's not the reason for this behaviour. You could put the same code in a `script` block and get the same result.

Comment: I think you are getting there, but to have a better overview of what's making that nested expression come alive and execute as it gets compiled you might want to read chrome [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) anc concentrate on "Inline JavaScript will not be executed" section.

Comment: Thanks for that documentation, it's a good read, but it's still not what was asked... According to what you linked, moving the code to an external .js file and using `addEventListener` would be secure in this case, yet if you put this code in that exact situation, it would still give out the same result. I agree that what you're trying to convey is more important than this particular situation in general, but it is not what this question is about.

Comment: But it is. You don't seem to understand dynamic scripting languages such as JavaScript. 
p.s.: FYI You cannot pas >> a string primitive of executable code<< to the addEventListener.